# POST request via urllib/urllib2?

Tags: python, post, request, urllib2, urllib

Before you say anything, I've looked around SO and the solutions didn't work. I need to make a post request to a login script in Python. The URL looks like http://example.com/index.php?act=login, then it accepts `username` and `password` via POST. Could anyone help me with this?

I've tried:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
opener.addheaders.append( ('Referer', 'http://www.hellboundhackers.org/index.php') )

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : '[redacted]',
                               'password' : '[redacted]'
                               })

resp = opener.open('http://[redacted].org/index.php?act=login', login_data)
print resp.read()
resp.close()
```

and a little bit modified:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
opener.addheaders.append( ('Referer', 'http://www.hellboundhackers.org/index.php') )

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'act' : 'login',
                               'username' : '[redacted]',
                               'password' : '[redacted]'
                               })

resp = opener.open('http://[redacted].org/index.php', login_data)
print resp.read()
resp.close()
```

Comment: It's certainly possible to make a post request from Python. Please show what you have tried, otherwise we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Be specific and what is the solution you've tried, and what is the problem/error you've encounter.

Comment: I've just edited the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to look at the HTML source to find out what the login form action URL is. Sometimes it is the same as the page URL itself, but it's probably different. But since you haven't shown actual URLs, we can't help you there.

The `<form>` element might look something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/do_login">
```

In that case, you would use `/do_login` in your POST url.

Comment: I spoke with the admin of the site, he said it uses POST. But I'll check it anyway. Thanks

`<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="/index.php?act=login">`

Comment: Okay, so it's the same page. So how do you know it's not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I studied the output (`print resp.read()`), and at the top, the login/signup buttons were still present. I also tried `test = opener.open('http://[redacted].org/index.php?act="app_view')` and then `print test.read()` after the resp lines, said I'm not logged in so I don't have access to that page.

Comment: There may be other aspects of the form post that you need to consider, such as hidden fields or cookies. These are common on login forms, and you may need to supply additional information. This can get fairly complex, and a good understanding of how forms and browsers work is essential.

Comment: Yeah, there was a hidden field. My friend spotted it :P. Thanks!