# Python not sending HTTP POST request to correct URL

Tags: python, http, post, request, urllib

I was lately making this ask.fm "spam" bot (no ask.fm doesn't have neither an IP limit nor a captcha to stop bots). So anyway, I made sure the url was correct, but every time I send the POST request to ask.fm/usernamehere it sends the request to ask.fm, I'm not sure why.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
print("What username do you want to spam?")
username = raw_input()
print("How many questions do you wanna spam?")
numQ = int(raw_input())
print("What is the question that you want to spam?")
Quest = raw_input()

url = "http://ask.fm/" + username
print(url)
for i in range(0, numQ):
    data = urllib.urlencode({'question[question_text]':Quest})
    headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/30.0.1835.59',
    'Host' : 'ask.fm',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer' : 'https://www.google.com.eg/',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'}
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    d = response.read()
    if(d.find("Your question has been sent") != -1):
        print("Successfully sent!")
    else:
        print("Failed to send!")
        print(d)
```

Basically there's no error, but the request is going to the wrong url, I've checked several times that the variable has the correct url, maybe it's redirecting? But how do I check redirects? And how would I make it act like as if the bot is a normal browser, I've already supplied the default headers for Opera.

Comment: I must say that I'm concerned with the ethics of assisting you in creating a working spambot.

Comment: I'm just going to use it on my own account to test it, I'm just using it for some practice, it would be really appreciated if you help, it's your choice though. :)

Comment: What is the "wrong URL" you mention? Also, I don't know Python, but I'm not sure you're using `urllib2.urlencode` properly (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). It's meant for encoding the query string of a URL. Is `data` going to be made part of the URL by the library?

Comment: Hrm. I'm surprised no Python people have answered this by now. I'll go ahead and add an answer of my own-- at least then I may get some rep if we get this worked out ;) BTW, you still didn't say what the "wrong URL" you mentioned is. It'd help to know. Also, have you tried any diagnostic tools like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? That's usually the first thing we .NET devs try in cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the help of [this PHP library](https://github.com/afilini/AskFmApi) I know what the problem is. You're missing the authenticity token, so ask.fm believes your request is fake (because it is).

Assuming the PHP library works, this is what you need to do:

1. **Scrape http://ask.fm to obtain the token you need to authenticate your request.**

For example, if you open up the site in your browser, you'll find something like the following:

```
  var AUTH_TOKEN = "aNotgbm1V9WvBGr//it4N2vSfhSBSP6nGZkx7rrnNL0=";
```

The PHP lib does this by getting the whole page into a string and using the RegEx `/(var AUTH_TOKEN = ")(.*)(";)/`.

2. **Include the token when you POST your question.**

Change your code to something like

```
data = urllib.urlencode({
    'question[question_text]':Quest,
    'authenticity_token':authToken
})
```

Where `authToken` is of course a variable containing the string you scraped from the site (in this example, `aNotgbm1V9WvBGr//it4N2vSfhSBSP6nGZkx7rrnNL0=`).

The PHP also adds `'question[force_anonymous]':1`. If the user sets `$anon` to true and they're logged in.

3. **Change your POST URL to http://ask.fm/[username]/questions/create/**

And that should be about it. I'd make sure you add all the HTTP headers the PHP lib uses as well:

```
CURLOPT_URL => "http://ask.fm/$nickname/questions/create/",  
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,  
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10 ,  
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10, 
CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://ask.fm/$nickname/",
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0',  
CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,  
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt",  
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt",  
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,  
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
```

BTW, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159376/post-request-via-urllib-urllib2) shows a different usage of `urllib2`. Just in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Would +1 but I just made this account and I have only reached a low amount of reputation points. Thanks anyways.